# Unable to initialize the driver in appium.Can not find the mistake. Attched screenshot

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am trying to setup a framework with junit cucumber but every time driver is returning `null` when I am extending in page class to use driver.findelements.

```
package core;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class DriverFactory {

    protected static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public void createdriver() throws MalformedURLException
    {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "MS OnePlus7");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\framework\\src\\test\\Resources\\APK\\Telegram.apk");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "62afbd2d");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }
}



package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import core.DriverFactory;

public class telegrampage extends DriverFactory {


    public void openhome()
    {
        System.out.println("driver is returning "+driver);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc='New Message']"));
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me why I am getting 'null' when I inherit from DriverFactory

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You should not upload pictures of code in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You never call createdriver() method.

Comment: @Angusiastysorry didn't get you..can you elaborate this please? how to do this in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `createdriver()` method before using `driver.findElement()` method.
Change your `openhome()` method to:

```
public void openhome()
{
    DriverFactory driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
    driverFactory.createdriver();
    System.out.println("driver is returning "+driver);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc='New Message']"));
}
```